# Should A/D resolution affect EEG signal properties and how?

Tags: eeg, resolution

I encounter a curious situation wherein the recording device of my EEG data appears to affect how many transients of definition "x" I find, especially strange since the amplitude criterion is relative (standard score instead of voltage).

One crucial difference is that the devices use different A/D resolution (12 vs. 22 bit) although they both encode the data in 16 bit (I already do not understand the difference between resolution and encoding, why both bit, but both different?).

To get to the point? How adjust for that difference? Also I excluded difference in sampling rate being crucial, because my current script adjusts for that based on two other devices I had to compare in the past, but which used the same A/D resolution...

Thank you dearly in advance!

Comment: 1 - What kind of transients?

2 - I suspect your 22-bit ADC is sigma-delta ADC. Sigma-delta ADCs will not react to a transient the same way as a SAR ADC would.

3 - TYpically, the data width should be equal or greater to your ADC resolution. So 12-bit ADC reading could be assigned to a 16-bit variable, without any loss of intormation. However, a 22-bit ADC would lose information if the reading is assigned to a 16-bit variable.

Comment: Thank you! How would you advise to correct post-hoc for the wrong assignment? Indeed I am looking for transients in the sigma range.

Comment: There's probably more going on here than you think.  At this point, I think we should assume that you have *two totally different data acquisition devices*, one of which *happens* to be 22 bit and the other of which *happens* to be 12 bit.  But we don't know what sort of anti-alias filtering is or is not there, or whether they have DC bias, or whether they have noise other than quantization noise, or how the signal is scaled to their range - etc., etc., etc.  At the very least, can you collect two **identical** signals with each input device, and post the graphs here?

Comment: That will not be easy :/ Due to the crisis I am remote from either device.

Comment: Can you post plots from each device of similar types of signals, or post any plot that details what you are seeing?

Comment: This would be the image, transient of interest is always at time-point zero and extents maximally half a second around that:

https://ibb.co/KFS8qyh

Comment: Dear all who still follow and want to/are able to help, I started understanding more (or so I think)

An EDF reader only displays the signals we recorded with the 22 bit device after FFT filtering, upon which they become undistinguishable from signals recorded with the old system.

However, my detection script for the transients I am interested in also applies filtering to the signals first, but they remain different enough to result in significantly different findings based on the device used. Does it only seem like it, or is there something special about the FFT filter of the EDF reader?

Comment: I am starting to understand now that the biggest issue might be, that the 22 bit files were also not prefiltered? What do you guys think? How can I best  recreate (in Matlab) the second order filters used by programs like System Evolution Plus?